# Wind Shield Wiper not working

Tags: windshield-wipers

I had a new windshield installed a few weeks ago...and now the wiper blade drivers side does not fully rotate to the left side...stops at about the 11:00 position should go to about 10:00 o'clock...any idea of how to correct?

Answer (score 2):

If the wiper also goes too low on the windshield. Then the wiper just needs readjusted. Remove the wiper and turn it the amount to compensate for the misalignment and tighten it back down. There are lots of different types of cars and types of wipers, you may have to do some googling or require special tools.

In all actuality the people who replaced the windshield had to remove the wipers in the first place. Just take it back the ask to have the wiper readjusted.